# When using Wish as suggested by the spell to do something other than duplicate a lower-level spell, will the caster still suffer?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

The PHB's description of [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) specifies a few different ways to use the spell:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect.
>
> Alternatively, you can create one of the following effects of your choice:

Examples include: healing allies, creating a mundane item worth 25K gp, granting resistance from a damage type, granting immunity to a damage type for 8 hours, etc.

Then later in the spell description, it states this:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. [...]

**Does that mean that if the caster creates a 25K gp diamond with *wish*, they still suffer the negative side effects?**

I originally thought that since they were suggested ways to use the spell, they were consequence-free.

Comment: 5e wizard retirement plan: 1) get to lv 17. 2) learn Wish. 3) sell 1/day clone vessels for half price (discard clone consciously).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### You will still get stress

Jeremy Crawford has clarified exactly this [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/795696477305606144):

> Wish spell: (1) Duplicated a spell of 8th level or lower? No stress. (2) Did anything else with wish? Stress. #DnD

A normal reading of the rules you already quote also specify "any effect other than duplicating a spell" so I think it is very clear that this is the case

Comment: I know it's a common phrase on this site, but for good reason: Spells do what they say. Adding that in wouldn't hurt this already good answer.

Comment: Looks like i need to apologize to my DM.

Comment: Basically, the "suggested uses" are simply something the spell can definitely do; anything beyond that requires GM approval. The suggested uses other than duplicating a lower-level spell still cause the negative side effects.

Comment: It doesn't help that one of the alternatives suggest "making yourself and your companions immune to a lich's life drain attack" for 8 hours. That reads like you're about to go lich hunting. Which if fine if you don't mind being carried into battle and casting a cantrip hurts you.